# In FreeCAD, how do you copy a sketch from one plane to another?

Tags: cad, freecad

I'm using FreeCAD, and I would like to duplicate a 2D sketch on another plane, but I can't seem to find an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m assuming you are working in the Part Design workbench. Select the sketch and click **Edit** > **Duplicate selected object**. Make sure that only the sketch is copied (depending on the version, either deselect the plane or click don’t include dependent objects). This will produce a duplicate sketch in the active body (if you want the duplicate in a different body, make sure it’s active first by double-clicking it if necessary). You can then click **Sketch** > **Reorient Sketch** to move it to a different plane.

By the way, FreeCAD has a very active and helpful forum at https://freecadweb.org. I highly recommend asking FreeCAD questions there.

Comment: Is it possible to move it into a new plane that is not XY XZ or YZ plane?

Comment: Yes, you click on the plane, then click "Map sketch to face" and select the sketch.